# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code while archive

Tags: swift, xcode

While trying to archive I am getting the error Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I have already tried to reinstall pod but still didn't work. I am getting the following error:

> PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/sushildhakal/Downloads/playkit-ios-samples-master/ChromecastSample/GoogleCast.framework/JapneseNepaliDictionary-fhxltmpnatbmdvebkseaepxdorwy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/JapneseNepaliDictionary/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/JapneseNepaliDictionary.build/Release-iphoneos/JapneseNepaliDictionary.build/Script-AE355B9BDA5EBF1B5927D6C4.sh (in target: JapneseNepaliDictionary)
>       cd /Users/sushildhakal/Desktop/JapneseNepaliDictionary
>       /bin/sh -c /Users/sushildhakal/Downloads/playkit-ios-samples-master/ChromecastSample/GoogleCast.framework/JapneseNepaliDictionary-fhxltmpnatbmdvebkseaepxdorwy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/JapneseNepaliDictionary/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/JapneseNepaliDictionary.build/Release-iphoneos/JapneseNepaliDictionary.build/Script-AE355B9BDA5EBF1B5927D6C4.sh
>   ComponentCommand PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code